# Zookeeper my ID not in the peer list

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper

I am working on deploying a dynamic Zookeeper cluster in Docker. I have it almost complete, but I am stuck in one area: the dynamic configuration parameters. I have an entrypoint script that reads the environmental variables passed to it regarding it's own ID and the IPs of the other Zookeeper servers.

Before Zookeeper starts, it writes it's id to `/tmp/zookeeper/$MYID/myid`, which is this case is 1. I am also writing `server.1=$MY_IP:2888:3888` to the `zoo.cfg` file.

If I try to start Zookeeper with `zkServer.sh start-foreground` with that configuration, it errors with:

```
root@7f23a5d1e5a1:/# zkServer.sh start-foreground
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2015-12-15 21:37:35,552 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@109] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2015-12-15 21:37:35,556 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@86] - Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: parameter: server.1 must be in a separate dynamic config file
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:244)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:126)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:110)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

However, if I remove the `server.1=$MY_IP:2888:3888` from the `zoo.cfg` file, it errors out with this:

```
2015-12-15 21:26:38,190 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@98] - Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.lang.RuntimeException: My id 0 not in the peer list
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:643)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:171)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:120)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
```

After [reading the docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperReconfig.html), I am still not sure where my configuration is messed up.

Here is my `zoo.cfg` file:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
quorumListenOnAllIPs=true
standaloneEnabled=false
dynamicConfigFile=/opt/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg.dynamic
server.1=192.168.1.46:2888:3888
```

Here is `myid` file:

```
root@7f23a5d1e5a1:/# cat /tmp/zookeeper/1/myid 
1
```

How can I fix this configuration and what is it supposed to look like? I am using Zookeeper 3.5.0-alpha.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved due to the way the Dockerfile executes commands. With the entrypoint script run inside the container on build, it wasn't reading any of the environmental variables as they didn't exist as part of the build process. When the entrypoint script was run as a child process/step of a run script - in this case, just a basic `run.sh` - on runtime, variables were then evaluated as they existed as part of the runtime.